# What does Command+M shortcut mean in IntelliJ Idea (Mac)?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I know this is stupid question but I'm always! mistakenly using this f.king short cut and IDE locks. So, I cannot click anything in the IDE.

I searched the Internet as well as http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf but didn't find what it is and how to escape. Currently I'm closing the IDE and rerun it. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the default [keymap sheet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) it doesn't actually do anything.

There might be a conflict with the OS default to minimise the window which is causing the application to lock.

Comment: I saw that minimise in Android studio. But in IntelliJ Idea just the IDE locks. other part of OS is working fine. Even in the ide if you right click on a package it shows context menu and you can add another package for example but your change is not visible and you can see the change after restart of the IDE!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running IntelliJ 13 Ultimate on Mavericks. Mine says it's supposed to Minimize the window.

[image]

In the interest of SCIENCE, I pressed Command-M. Sure enough, it locked up my IDE. I had to kill it to continue working.